# Remove text from Output in MySql

Tags: mysql

My Out put is :

I want to remove the **http://** when I get my output in the MySQL Workbench.

```
ID  URL

1   http://www.christiantoday.com/article/samsung.galaxy.note.4.vs.htc.one.m8.buy.now.wait/38212.htm
2   http://www.christiantoday.com/article/samsung.galaxy.note.4.vs.htc.one.m8.buy.now.wait/38212.htm
3   http://www.christiantoday.com/article/samsung.galaxy.note.4.vs.htc.one.m8.buy.now.wait/38212.htm
```

I want it to be :

```
ID  URL
1   www.christiantoday.com/article/samsung.galaxy.note.4.vs.htc.one.m8.buy.now.wait/38212.htm
2   www.christiantoday.com/article/samsung.galaxy.note.4.vs.htc.one.m8.buy.now.wait/38212.htm
3   www.christiantoday.com/article/samsung.galaxy.note.4.vs.htc.one.m8.buy.now.wait/38212.htm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select replace(url, 'http://', '') as url
from your_table
```